# MySQL/Doctrine - Search in all columns and joined tables

Tags: mysql, search, doctrine

I have a table in MySQL database with about 30 text fields and about 10 joined N-N tables.

My client wants one form input field to search through all the data.

Is there an easy way to do it?

My assumption is that if I do so many joins, the query is going to take ages.

So an idea I had is to create a column called "ALL". After each edit/add action I would dump all the other columns' date into this ALL column and do a search like this:

```
Select * From Table WHERE all like "%search"
```

Is it possible to do it like this? Anyone knows the right way to do it?

Thank you, Mike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, right

Commonly, there is another (distinct) column 'all' that is a tuple of all values of all columns and then you search through that column.

Another option is to add a different database just for a sake of fulltext

- https://www.elastic.co/
- https://www.algolia.com/